# Signing Module on Non-UEFI Boards

Tags: grub2, kernel, uefi, signature

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with the 4.4.0-57 kernel and I want to install a self-made module. The BIOS is a non UEFI BIOS (Kontron 986LCD-M/mITX).

I tried to sign the module by following this [procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) but the result of step 3 (`sudo mokutil --import MOK.der`) is `EFI variables are not supported on this system`.

I tried to follow this [recipe](https://github.com/Canonical-kernel/Ubuntu-kernel/blob/master/Documentation/module-signing.txt) but I cannot find the public keys.

How can I sign a module on a non UEFI board?

====================================================

Update 1:
It seems to be a fairy tale that only modules running with a UEFI Bios have to use signed modules under 16.04:

```
I use as grub option: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" acpi_enforce_resources=lax"`. 

I get the error `module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel` in dmesg if I try to load a module via modprobe.

`sudo mokutil --disable-validation` returns the error `EFI variables are not supported on this system`
```

================ Update 1 ===================================================

I am sorry but this statement is wrong:

> The procedure to which you refer describes disabling Secure Boot
>   validation, not signing modules. There's no need to sign kernel
>   modules on non-UEFI systems, since Secure Boot is exclusively a UEFI
>   feature.

The kernel should work in this way it doesn't. I experiance it because I get always the error message I get the `error module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel` in dmesg and the kernel is not loaded.

================ Update 2 ===================================================
How can I install shim on a non uefi motherboard:

```
# aptitude search shim
p   grub-splashimages                                   - a collection of great GRUB splashimages
p   grub2-splashimages                                  - a collection of great GRUB2 splashimages
p   libjs-es5-shim                                      - ECMAScript 5 compat. shims for old JavaScript engines (library
p   libjs-es6-shim                                      - ECMAScript 6 compat. shims for legacy JavaScript engines (libr
p   node-es5-shim                                       - ECMAScript 5 compat. shims for old JavaScript engines (Node.js
p   node-es6-shim                                       - ECMAScript 6 compat. shims for legacy JavaScript engines (Node
p   olpc-kbdshim                                        - Dienst zur OLPC-XO-Tastaturunterstützung
v   olpc-kbdshim-common                                 -
v   olpc-kdbshim-hal                                    -
p   ruby-launchy-shim                                   - helper class for launching a web browser
p   shimmer-themes                                      - Gtk+ themes from Shimmer Project
p   shimmer-wallpapers                                  - Wallpapers from Shimmer Project
p   systemd-shim                                        - shim für systemd
p   yoshimi                                             - Software-Synthesizer, basiert auf ZynAddSubFX
p   yoshimi-data                                        - Voreinstellungen für Yoshimi
```

Is `systemd-shim` correct? I believe that it will not work because it is a non-uefi MB...

Comment: BIOS has not supported Secure boot as that is a UEFI thing. So I do not see how you can sign kernel or drivers on a BIOS system.

Comment: Please can you explain me why I get this error when I try to load it: `module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a huge bug in Ubuntu. `mokutil` and `MokManager` can only sign your own modules if you have MB which support uefi. Older MB under Ubuntu 16.04 which do not support uefi cannot sign modules with `mokutil` and `MokManager`. You will get always a responds like `EFI variables are not supported on this system` or similar.

It is claimed that the signing is just enabled by the kernel for uefi MB. I'm sorry but this is wrong. This is also shown e.g. by these kernel parameter:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_UEFI=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA512=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_HASH="sha512"
CONFIG_EFI_SECURE_BOOT_SIG_ENFORCE=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="certs/signing_key.pem"
CONFIG_CHECK_SIGNATURE=y
CONFIG_SIGNATURE=y
```

As I said this are the kernel parameter for a non uefi MB which don’t make sense, especially `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_UEFI=y`.

You have to recompile the kernel and switch off the signing options. They can be found by `grep -v ^# /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep _SIG`. Especially `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG` and `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL` should be set to `n`. However, this has a clear disadvantage because you have to put the kernel update on hold and you’ll have to recompile every new kernel. It’s frustrating.

Comment: I report a bug on ubuntu: 1656670

Comment: Note that `mokutil` and `MokManager.efi` are EFI-only tools; it's *not* a bug that they work only on EFI-only systems, any more than it's a bug that a Linux binary doesn't run under DOS. That said, it sounds like you've uncovered a serious bug in the kernel; it should not be insisting on signed kernel modules on non-EFI systems.

Comment: I agree that mokutil and MokManager.efi are efi tools only and that’s not the bug. Sorry, if I was unclear. `efi` needs a 64bit system even if the board is a uefi board. However, Ubuntu has to distinguish 3 scenarios: i) a bios board with 32/64 bit Ubuntu, ii) a uefi board with a 32 bit Ubuntu and iii) a uefi board with a 64 bit Ubuntu. The efi tools will only work in scenario iii). Therefore, it will affect especially small devices like mobile and entertainment devices because they run dominantly on 32 bit and need probably always proprietary driver.

Answer (score -1):

The procedure to which you refer describes disabling Secure Boot validation, not signing modules. There's no need to sign kernel modules on non-UEFI systems, since Secure Boot is exclusively a UEFI feature.

That said, if you did want to sign kernel modules on a non-UEFI system, you *should* be able to do so. (I've not tried it, but AFAIK all the tools are Linux userspace tools that do not rely on Secure Boot being available or active.) You might do this if you wanted to build a package with signed modules for installation on other systems. Note that you'll need to install your own keys on the target systems, which can be tedious; see below for pointers. To sign kernel modules:

1. Create a set of signing keys. This is a complex task. I recommend you read [my page on Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#shim) for information on creating signing keys.
2. Locate the `sign-file` binary. This binary is not normally installed where Linux binaries are installed; instead, it comes with kernel headers. The command `find /usr/src/ -name sign-file` should locate it if it's installed on your system. If this command returns nothing, you must install a kernel headers package.
3. Sign the binary with a command like `/path/to/sign-file sha256 /key/path/your.key /key/path/your.cer /path/to/module/module.ko`

At this point, the binary `module.ko` will be signed with your key (`your.key` and `your.cer`). To be used, your key must be registered with the target system, presumably in the MOK list. To do this, you must install it with `MokManager.efi`, as detailed on [my Secure Boot page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#shim)

I'd like to emphasize again, though, that signing kernel modules is *not* necessary except on systems that are booting in UEFI mode with Secure Boot active -- and even then, it's necessary only for third-party or locally-compiled kernel modules, such as commercial video drivers or the VirtualBox kernel modules. Most of the kernel modules provided with the Ubuntu kernel are already signed with the same Canonical key that's used to sign GRUB and the main Ubuntu kernel file.

Comment: Dear Rod, thank you very much for your answer. However, I referred already in my question to such a solution which unfortunately doesn’t work. I use as grub option: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" acpi_enforce_resources=lax"`. I get the error `module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel` in dmesg. Do you have another solution?

Comment: I stand by my answer; however, it's clear that you've encountered a bug in the Linux kernel distributed by Ubuntu. Signing kernel modules is not done with `mokutil`, but with `sbsign`; `mokutil` is used to *install* a signing key in an EFI-based computer's NVRAM. Thus, you seem to be working under some misunderstandings of how EFI Secure Boot and related tools work, which is making it harder for you to negotiate the issue and even ask for help. As this is a bug, filing a bug report (as you've done) is appropriate. I know of no workarounds for this bug, aside from recompiling a custom kernel.

Comment: I stopped experimenting with the efi tools. As you said, it is of no sense. However I have started to build a custom kernel. The many issue here is to find to prober parameter to disable (not so easy since the build of a custom kernel takes hours). Do you have comments on my selection? Thanks in advance http://askubuntu.com/questions/871924/which-kernel-parameters-for-recompilation-have-to-be-changed-because-i-cannot-lo